# Backslash SelectSingleNode Escape

Tags: escaping, backslash, selectsinglenode

In Javascript I have an XML DOM.  I am trying to select a node within the DOM by using SelectSingleNode.  Something like cell.SelectSingleNode(stuff [@attrjunk = 'MATCH']).  So what I want to match on has a backslash .  What do I replace the MATCH with to match on abc\xyz??  I've tried abc\xyz and abc\xyz but neither seems to work unfortunately...

Answer (score 0):

Try `abc\\xyz`.